# Finding a line in a given a parallelity with a plane, and intersection with another known line

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm looking for the line $l_1$ which intersects with the line

$$l_2:\begin{cases}
x = 1 &+& t \\
y = 2 &-& 2t \\
z = -1 &+& t
\end{cases}$$

and is also parallel with the plane

$$\Theta:x+3y+z=1$$

On top of all of this, $l_1$ also goes through the point $P:(1,2,2)$.

---

#### Own attempt

I find the parallel plane $\Theta':x+3y+z-9=0$. I found this by substituting $(1,2,2)$ into $\Theta$, to find a plane at which that coordinate lies on.

- The reason I did all that?

Considering that $l_1 \parallel \Theta \iff l_1 \parallel \Theta'$. Combined with the fact that $l_1$ intersects with $l_2$, we have that $l_1$ must go through the points $P$ and whatever point is the intersection point for $l_2$ and $\Theta'$.

By using $l_2$ and $\Theta'$ together, we find that:

$$\begin{eqnarray}(1+t)+3(2-2t)+(-1+t)-9=0\\
\iff-3-4t=0\\
\iff \frac{-3}{4}=t\end{eqnarray}$$

Using this parameter-value in $l_2$, we find that $l_2$ intersects with $\Theta'$ at $I:(\frac{1}{4},\frac{5}{4},-\frac{7}{4})$.

Since we know two points which $l_1$ passes through ($I$ and $P$), we can now figure out the direction vector $\textbf{v}$.

$$\textbf{v}:\Delta(P\land I) = (\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{15}{4})$$

Since $\textbf{v}$ is just a direction vector, we can multiply by 4 and we get

$$\textbf{v'}=(3,3,15)$$

$$\therefore l_1:\begin{cases}
x = 1 &+& 3t \\
y = 2 &+& 3t \\
z = 2 &+& 15t
\end{cases}$$

**How can I verify this?**

I tried setting $l_{1_x} = l_{2_x}$ etc.. but that did not yield the point $I$.

Comment: You found the wrong I. I should be $(1/4, 7/2, -7/4)$.

Comment: @KittyL Ah, and that solved everything. Thank you Kitty. Such long question for such small mistake. On the upside, I think I grasped this better after writing this down.

Comment: It always does so. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is as the following.

Assume the equation of $l_1$ is:
$$
\begin{cases}
x=x_0+au \\
y=y_0+bu\\
z=z_0+cu\\
\end{cases}
$$
Since it passes $(1,2,2)$, then take this point as $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$, and at this point $u=0$.

And we can always take $a=1$ since $u$ is of any scale, then we only need to know $b$ and $c$. (It is also true for $b$ or $c$.)

The vector of $l_1$ is $(1,b,c)$, and the normal of $\Theta$ is $(1,3,1)$. The scalar product is $0$. 
$$
1+3b+c=0
$$

$l_1$ and $l_2$ has a intersection point, therefore:
$$
\begin{cases}
1+t=1+u \\
2-2t=2+bu\\
-1+t=2+cu\\
\end{cases}
$$
We have $b=-2$, and then, use the scalar product condition, we have $c=5$. Therefore:
$$
\begin{cases}
x=1+u \\
y=2-2u\\
z=2+5u\\
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The intersection point of $l_2$ with $\Theta'$ is at $I:$ $\left({1 \over 4}, {7 \over 2}, {-7 \over 4} \right)$, and the final equation of $l_1$ is:
$$
\begin{cases}
x=1+1u \\
y=2-2u\\
z=2+5u\\
\end{cases}
$$